# Why should I not initialize static variable in header?

Tags: c++, oop, initialization, static-initialization

So, let's say I have a header like this:

```
#ifndef BASECLASS_H
#define BASECLASS_H

class BaseClass
{
    public:
        static int getX(){return x;}
    private:
        static int x;
};

int BaseClass::x = 10;

#endif
```

I have heard many times that I should not initialise static variables inside a header, but rather in cpp. But as there are guards, there should be only one copy of `BaseClass::x`. So I kinda do not understand why I should put

```
int BaseClass::x = 10;
```

in cpp.

Comment: The question phrasing and answers here are superior to those in the nominated question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you do it in the header, you'll get multiple definition errors as soon as you include it from more than one CPP file.  You're really telling the compiler two things when you declare

```
int BaseClass::x = 10;
```

First, you're defining the symbol BaseClass::x; second you're telling it you want it to have the initial value of 10.  According to the [One Definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) this can only happen once in your program.

Comment: I think I start getting the idea, but is there any way to demonstrate it? Is it that I need to write two different programs, which include BaseClass and run them simultaneosly?

Comment: @user3496846 no you just need to have a single program consisting of (at least) two cpp files, both of which include your header.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it's easier to understand if you think about what the preprocessor actually does: It copies the content of all included header files into the cpp file and passes this to the compiler.

Now let's say you have:

```
// In a.cpp
#include <baseclass.h>

// more code

// In b.cpp
#include <baseclass.h>

// more code
```

After the preprocessor expands the includes, both files will contain:

```
int BaseClass::x = 10;
```

Now as soon as both object files are passed to the linker, it will see the symbol `BaseClass::x` twice - which is an error.

Now, to make it even more obvious, imagine you would put this in a header file:

```
int aGlobalVariable = 10;
```

And then include it in two different cpp files, which should both be linked into one executable. It's actually not any different from your example, if seen from the linker's point of view.

**Why is this not a problem with class declarations?**

There's a difference between *declarations* and *definitions*. Only the latter will cause problems. E.g., all of the following are declarations:

- `extern int a;`
- `void foo(int a);`
- `class Foo { int bar(); };`

Whereas these are definitions:

- `int a;`
- `int b = 10;`
- `void foo(int a) { /*..*/ }`
- `int Foo::bar() { /*...*/ }`

As long as there is one (and only one) definition, you can have as many declarations as you'd like, and the linker will make sure they all refer to the same function or memory location.

Now what about classes? Classes can only be declared, while their member functions and static members have to be defined. Again, each definition may only exist once.

Member functions and static members actually exist only once in a program's address space, whereas normal members (instance variables) exist for each object of the class.

Getting back to your specific problem: static members are basically just global variables, but scoped to the class' name.

Hope this clears things up for you!

Comment: But besides the #include "baseClass.h", won't the linker also include double definition of the class itself, which should also cause a problem? Sorry, it can take time for me to understand...

Comment: No, because it's just a class *declaration*. I'll add a bit about that to my answer

Comment: OK, thank you very much for such a descriptive answer, I think I start getting the idea :)

Answer (score 4):

The guards do not prevent multiple copies in multiple source files. They only prevent multiple copies in one source file.

You will be violating the one definition rule if you have multiple source files that `#include "base_class.h"`.

Answer (score 2):

Because If you initialize it in the header there is a possibility that it would be defined in multiple locations if you include the header more than once. Which will result in a linker error